# Why would I get a CSP violation for the blocked-uri 'about'?

Tags: content-security-policy

My CSP report URI has received the following CSP violation:

```
{
  "csp-report":{
    "document-uri":"https://example.com/blog/somepage",
    "referrer":"",
    "violated-directive":"img-src 'self' data: p.typekit.net pbs.twimg.com platform.twitter.com q.stripe.com syndication.twitter.com",
    "effective-directive":"img-src",
    "original-policy": veryLongPolicyGoesHere,
    "blocked-uri":"about",
    "status-code":0
  }
}
```

Why would I get a CSP violation for the blocked-uri 'about'?

Is this the inbuilt `about:` URL from web browsers? I can't replicate the problem when I try.

Comment: I'm also seeing this from one particular user on a system with maybe 30-50 different users. I, too, can't fathom why the CSP violation is being triggered, but the particular user has a pretty old version of Chrome (38) on OS X 10.6, so that could be one reason; alternatively, it could be a browser extension, but we've yet to identify a particular one (they mentioned using Adblock and Disconnect, but they might have others).

Comment: The question is from 2015, so just for info, there is a web platform test for that case since 2017, which should prevent that behaviour in modern browser: https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/master/content-security-policy/frame-src/frame-src-about-blank-allowed-by-default.sub.html

Comment: @RiZKiT that's a useful comment but you might want to let people know what 'web platform' is. My own understanding is: "CSP violations for about:blank should no longer occur in current browsers that confirm to the web platform tests, which includes most major browsers"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I worked with the user to discover it is indeed the [Disconnect](https://disconnect.me/) extension  that is causing this. I contacted the people making the extension, and they confirmed they block URIs by replacing them with `about:blank`; this is what is causing the CSP violations.

Until Disconnect fixes their blocking scheme, I think the best approach is to simply ignore the CSP violation reports when `blocked-uri` is `about`.

Comment: Hello @mikemaccana. I've added `script-src 'self' about` but it doesn't work. Should I add `about:blank`? Please suggest

Comment: `about:blank` is considered an invalid source. It seems like uBlock Origin does the same thing that Disconnect did: when it blocks something in a web page, it's replaced with `about:blank`.  I have not found a workaround for this yet.

Comment: I think I may have found a **temporary** workaround (until whatever causes `about:blank` on the page is fixed): adding `about:` to the directives that are violated.  I tried adding it to the `default-src`, but I still received a violation report.  I added it to `img-src` and `script-src`, and the violations did not show up.  This may resolve your issue, @RomanMarusyk

Comment: @Tiffany You should turn your comment into an answer, I believe it would be a better answer than the explanation given in the answer above. I would probably award it the bounty (but hurry, the bounty expires in 3 hours!)

Comment: @Clément my apologies, just noticed your comment now. I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think I may have found a temporary workaround (until whatever causes `about:blank`on the page is fixed): adding `about:` to the directives that are violated. I tried adding it to the `default-src`, but I still received a violation report. I added it to `img-src` and `script-src`, and the violations did not show up.

Comment: That's useful, but it also sounds like a browser bug. Worth reporting it as an issue in the browser!

Comment: Your specific situation, yes, it sounds like a browser bug. But there may be other reasons an `about:` violation comes up, which is what I was experiencing when I was researching this.

Comment: No I mean your specific situation: adding to `default.src` not affecting the individual sources.